# How to use a Red/Green color map in Blender?

Tags: normal-map, artifacts

(I have modified my initial question after finding out more about the normal maps.)

I am playing around with some ripped models and I am trying to figure out how to use the normal maps that come with them. They only have the Red and Green color channels and it seems the Blue channel needs to be generated. Is this something Blender can do easily? Can I use a material node setup to create the Blue channel at run time?

[image: An red/green normal map]

---

Edit:

I have found two plausible ways to fix the normal maps. The first is suggested by Christopher below and is  to invert the normal map and to invert the green channel afterwards to get the correct direction.

The second is from [Substance](https://docs.substance3d.com/integrations/working-with-normals-in-unity-194216104.html) in an article about Normals in Unity engine. It seems that the blue channel can be dropped because the normals are always of length 1, so the Blue channel can be recovered by:

B = sqrt( 1 - R*R - G*G)

which I have implemented using nodes below.

I am leaning towards the Substance approach, however, when I check the RGB values in Python, it seems that parts of the mouth have Normal vectors with length greater than 1, so this would be invalid for the approach suggested by the substance article.

Does anyone have any further suggestions about the correct approach?

[image]

Comment: maybe if you plug that image in both Red and Blue sockets of CombineRGB node and something else in blue socket (maybe the standard normal map color), it could work. It will work only if that map really was used as normal map because color of the map doesn't mean anything

Comment: It seems like the normal map is a BC5 type normal map. I found something on it here: https://docs.substance3d.com/integrations/working-with-normals-in-unity-194216104.html

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting the image before connecting to the Normal Map Node to get back the purple (tangent space) colors (and map) you're used to seeing (color not shown).

[image: Invert]

However, looking more closely, I'm assuming the eyelids and nostrils are supposed to be protruding from the "outwards" face (hard to tell using the low res sample). If this is how you need it to be, you may also need to do a DirectX to OpenGL conversion:

[image: Invert2]

Comment: I found this article on compressed normal maps from Substance. It seems that the blue channel is removed and can be recovered later.

https://docs.substance3d.com/integrations/working-with-normals-in-unity-194216104.html

Comment: I have tried both your method and the method suggested in the Substance article. Your method gives better results. Is this a common way for Normal maps to be saved for games?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. At first I thought it was an _Object Space_ or _World Space_ Normal map (based on the color), but connecting it using either of those didn't give very nice results. So, I just started trying some of the conversions I know, and this one seems to give correct results for a _Tangent Space_ Normal map, providing the desired surface deformation directions and accurate "shadow" angles.